How to handle a HTTP request differently based on whether or not response is an SSE stream
Is it possible to handle normal endpoints and SSE endpoints uniformly in Javascript?
In particular, I was wondering if it is possible to have the backend decide whether a web request should be handled by just returning the current state or by subscribing to the state with an initial response plus further events with updates to the state in the response.
